# How Adjust Activity on Keypad is shown

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Activity masked as Dialog. 
I would like to adjust the activity when the keypad is shown.

My layout resource:

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
          ...
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: The Problem was android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somethimes android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"   is causing some problems and the window is not resized. Remove it to see if it works and than check for an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

There is not any setting in manifest you can do to achieve this you have to add an extra view of height (something you want ) and width 0 to your layout at the end of the layout. Just make it visible when keypad appears. To find state of keypad use this

```
 int lastDiff = 0; 
 public static boolean keypadopen;
```

and to your onCreate() add this

```
 addKeyBoardHandler();
```

it will set boolean keypadopen with the current status of keypad.If it is true then add an extra view of required height which will scroll up the view.

```
private void addKeyBoardHandler()
    {
        final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.container);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                if (lastDiff == heightDiff) return;
                lastDiff = heightDiff;
                System.out.println("Keypad height :"+heightDiff);
                if (heightDiff > 100)
                {
                     keypadopen = true;
                    keypadListner.onKeypadOpen(heightDiff+10);
                }
                else
                {   
                    keypadopen = false;
                    keypadListner.onKeypadOpen(heightDiff+10);

                }
            }
        });
```

where container is the id of the root view.

Comment: well I found this on Android Developer but it doesn't work...
http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

Comment: Yeah I know, but have u tried above solution ? It will work no doubt.

Comment: what Rect is...? I thisk miss somethis like keypadopen, keypadListner, lastDiff to work

Comment: int lastDiff = 0; public static boolean keypadopen;                and to your onCreate() add this addKeyBoardHandler();  it will set boolean keypadopen with the current status of keypad.If it is true then add an extra view of required height which will scroll up the view.

Comment: Rect is rectangle to get the change in the view so that we can identify that keypad status.

Comment: @alfo888_ibg see the changes I made to answer.